# how to convert the parameters into the description if parameters have more than three in TextField from Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 3 parameters in the report. I want to convert all the id parameter in the description in my TextField.

```
The first parameter is $P{address}
if $P{address} = 1 then "Port Garden"
else if $P{address} = 2 then "pangsa maju,indah"
else if $P{address} = 3 then "eastern mouth"
else null

The second parameter is the $P{city}
if $P{city} = 1 then "Gosa"
else $P{city} = 2 "Marang"
else if $P{city} = 3 "kuala seberang"
else null

The third parameter is the $P{country}
if $P{country} = 198 then "China"
else if $P{country} = 234 then "Bangladesh"
else if $P{country} = 390 then "Sri Lanka"
else null
```

When I key in the parameter, I want to all the parameters that changed the description in Textfield.

```
For example. "Information for company the address is $P{address}=1, city is $P{city}=1 and country is $P{country}=198".
The result is "Information for the company address is Port garden, city is Gosa and country is China.
```

Anyone know about this?.:(

Answer (score 1):

Hard-coding the values into the report like this is odd. It's probably a bad idea.

But despite being a bad idea... it's not hard to do. Use something like this. Create a parameter called $P{Country_Name}. Give it a default value using the ternary operator (multiple times) like this:

```
$P{country}==198 ? "China" : 
  $P{country}==234 ? "Bangladesh" : 
    $P{country}==390 ? "Sri Lanka" : "somewhere else"
```

Comment: i have try your solution but it doesn't works.Can you check what's problem with my code?.:(

Comment: $P{Country_Name} has its default value based on $P{country} in my example. You have $P{pd_id} referring to itself in its default value. This won't work.

Comment: i'm not understand what do you mean for $P{Country_Name} and $P{country}?. im so confuse.Why you put 2 parameter.i just want for one parameter and one description.How to do that?.can you show me more example.can you modified my code so that i know where is my mistakes?

Comment: When I wrote, "Create a parameter called $P{Country_Name}." I meant, "Create a parameter called $P{Country_Name}." I didn't mean "add a default value to your existing parameter." You have one Integer with the ID and you need a second parameter that converts this ID to the appropriate String.